# How to set a response message based on time access in DialogFlow Mobile platform?

Tags: mobile, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, diagflow

I'm looking how to set in `DialogFlow` a specified message that the `bot` will answer at specified time, like *"out of working hours, come later"* if a visitor  engages it beyond specified hours .

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In short - no.

Dialogflow is designed for user-driven queries - where the user says something and the bot immediately replies (or replies within about 5 seconds).

There is no mechanism where the bot can reply unless it is prompted first.

Comment: In this case the bot can't take the timezone in the server to say specific things?

Comment: It can, but it can't wait until a time specified by the user. Perhaps you may wish to update your original question to clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to set a specific message at hours, like if you have hours of attention and anyone use the bot out of that hours then the bot will response "sorry, we are out" or something like that